# Bootstrap Multiselect setting the options fields

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-multiselect

I am attempting to have the search bar on my bootstrap-multiselect object. The problem is I do not know how to use javascript options.

I am using this tutorial: www.htmluse.com/bootstrap-multiselect

I have the multiselect visually appearing correctly, but I don't know how to set the options. I've attempted this...

```
$('.multiselect').enableFiltering = true;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following the [documentation](http://davidstutz.github.io/bootstrap-multiselect/):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('.multiselect').multiselect({
            enableFiltering: true
        });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'll give it a shot. When using other jquery plugins I usually include the options this way.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.multiselect').multiselect({
        enableFiltering: true,
        buttonWidth: 100px,
        //...
    });
});
```